# Discord JS, discord-buttons; How to attach more than 5 buttons to a message?

Tags: javascript, button, discord

How to attach more than 5 buttons to a message with discord-buttons, discord.js?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1qpJ.png)

The way I try:

```js
let Buttons = [];
    Buttons[0] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("0").setLabel(' ');
    Buttons[1] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("1").setLabel(' ');
    Buttons[2] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("2").setLabel(' ');

    Buttons[3] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("3").setLabel(' ');
    Buttons[4] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("4").setLabel(' ');
    Buttons[5] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("5").setLabel(' ');
    
    Buttons[6] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("6").setLabel(' ');
    Buttons[7] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("7").setLabel(' ');
    Buttons[8] = new discordButton.MessageButton().setStyle('gray').setID("8").setLabel(' ');

msg.channel.send(`⁣...`, { buttons:Buttons });
```

The error it gets:

```js
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
components[0].components[5]: The specified component exceeds the maximum width
components[0].components[6]: The specified component exceeds the maximum width
components[0].components[7]: The specified component exceeds the maximum width
components[0].components[8]: The specified component exceeds the maximum width

method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/656858400440975371/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400
}
```

Does it have something to do with my bot account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you read through or reference the [Discord API documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/), here you could find out the following information:

- Buttons must be sent inside an Action Row
- An Action Row can contain up to 5 buttons

Reference: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components

Comment: How many total action rows are allowed? 5 as well? Therefore at most you can have 25 buttons in one embed?

Answer (score 5):

You can try doing this:

```
const msg = await message.channel.send({
      embed: YOUR EMBED HERE,
      components: [
        {
          type: 1,
          components: [Button[0], Button[1], Button[2], Button[3], Button[4]],
        },
        {
          type: 1,
          components: [more, buttons, here, max, 5]
        }
        {
          type: 1,
          components: [you, can, do, 5, times]
        }
      ]
  });
```

I hope this helped :D

Comment: thhhxxx it workeed for me