# ErrorName => DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**I could not solve the problem with this code, although I tried in several ways. I hope someone can help me with this**

**CODE:**

```
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "get-roles")) {
    let roles_notifications = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("notification_1")
        .setLabel("All Notifications")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
        new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("notification_2")
        .setLabel("YouTube Uploads")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
        new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("notification_3")
        .setLabel("Twitter Uploads")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
        new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("notification_4")
        .setLabel("Server News")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
        new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("notification_5")
        .setLabel("Server Updates")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
        new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("notification_6")
        .setLabel("Anime News")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
        new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("notification_7")
        .setLabel("Anime Episodes")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY"),
    )
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("Select role")
    let msg = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [roles_notifications] })
    let iFilter = i => i.user.id === message.author.id;
    let collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: iFilter, time: 3600000 })

    collector.on("collect", async r => {
        if (r.customId === "notification_1") {
            let role_1 = message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.roles.all_notifications)
            if (message.member.roles.cache ?.has(role_1.id)) {
                message.member.roles.remove(role_1.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Removed The ${role_1} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            } else {
                message.member.roles.add(role_1.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Added The ${role_1} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            }
        } else if (r.customId === "notification_2") {
            let role_2 = message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.roles.youTube_uploads)
            if (message.member.roles.cache ?.has(role_2.id)) {
                message.member.roles.remove(role_2.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Removed The ${role_2} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            } else {
                message.member.roles.add(role_2.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Added The ${role_2} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            }
        } else if (r.customId === "notification_3") {
            let role_3 = message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.roles.twitter_uploads)
            if (message.member.roles.cache ?.has(role_3.id)) {
                message.member.roles.remove(role_3.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Removed The ${role_3} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            } else {
                message.member.roles.add(role_3.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Added The ${role_3} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            }
        } else if (r.customId === "notification_4") {
            let role_4 = message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.roles.server_news)
            if (message.member.roles.cache ?.has(role_4.id)) {
                message.member.roles.remove(role_2.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Removed The ${role_2} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            } else {
                message.member.roles.add(role_4.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Added The ${role_4} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            }
        }  else if (r.customId === "notification_5") {
            let role_5 = message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.roles.server_updates)
            if (message.member.roles.cache ?.has(role_5.id)) {
                message.member.roles.remove(role_5.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Removed The ${role_5} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            } else {
                message.member.roles.add(role_5.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Added The ${role_5} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            }
        } else if (r.customId === "notification_6") {
            let role_6 = message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.roles.anime_news)
            if (message.member.roles.cache ?.has(role_6.id)) {
                message.member.roles.remove(role_6.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Removed The ${role_6} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            } else {
                message.member.roles.add(role_6.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Added The ${role_6} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            }
        } else if (r.customId === "notification_7") {
            let role_7 = message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.roles.anime_episodes)
            if (message.member.roles.cache ?.has(role_7.id)) {
                message.member.roles.remove(role_7.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Removed The ${role_7} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            } else {
                message.member.roles.add(role_7.id)
                r.reply({ content: `Added The ${role_7} Role!`, ephemeral: true })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

});

**ERROR:**

```
/home/runner/System-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
  throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
        ^
```

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
components[0].components[5]: The specified component exceeds the maximum width
components[0].components[6]: The specified component exceeds the maximum width
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/System-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/System-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
at async TextChannel.send (/home/runner/System-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
method: 'post',
path: '/channels/947233067129516093/messages',
code: 50035,
httpStatus: 400,
requestData: {
json: {
content: undefined,
tts: false,
nonce: undefined,
embeds: [
{
title: null,
type: 'rich',
description: 'Select role',
url: null,
timestamp: 0,
color: null,
fields: [],
thumbnail: null,
image: null,
author: null,
footer: null
}
],
components: [
{
components: [
[Object], [Object],
[Object], [Object],
[Object], [Object],
[Object]
],
type: 1
}
],
username: undefined,
avatar_url: undefined,
allowed_mentions: undefined,
flags: undefined,
message_reference: undefined,
attachments: undefined,
sticker_ids: undefined
},
files: []
}
}

Comment: Maybe you should **read the documentation** ...?!? https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons: _"WARNING: You can have a maximum of five ActionRows per message, and five buttons within an ActionRow."_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord JS, discord-buttons; How to attach more than 5 buttons to a message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777764/discord-js-discord-buttons-how-to-attach-more-than-5-buttons-to-a-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `discord.js`, you can only have up to five buttons within an [`MessageActionRow`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageActionRow), so all you have to do is remove the last two [`MessageButton`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageButton)s to remove the error. But if you still want all the buttons to be displayed, you can add another [`MessageActionRow`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageActionRow) in your code having the last two buttons and send them together so that your code looks like this:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "get-roles")) {
    let firstMessageActionRow = new Discord.MessageActionRow() // The first MessageActionRow
    let secondMessageActionRow = new Discord.MessageActionRow() // The second MessageActionRow

    await message.channel.send({
      embeds: [embed],
      components: [firstMessageActionRow, secondMessageActionRow],
    });
  }
});
```